# How do I insert a new blank PowerPoint slide without leaving presentation mode?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Surface Book with a pen that I use with PowerPoint for lectures.  I like being able to scribble on my slides with the pen, but sometimes, e.g., if I'd like to draw a whole diagram in response to an interesting question, it would be a lot easier if I could simply insert a new blank slide without ever leaving presentation mode.  Even better if I could do it with some magic click with the pen.

Is there any way to insert a blank slide without leaving presentation mode?

Comment: Not without some programming (usually in VBA).  However, you could pre-insert a few hidden blank slides and include links to them in your slide master so you could click to jump there at need.  With a keyboard, you can also press the number of the slide you want to jump to, then ENTER to go there; I'd imagine there's some kind of Surface equivalent for this.

Comment: See, presentation mode is demoing pptx which is read-only like pdf. It goes against the design philosophy to give such a feature. Just head back and Ctrl+M, no one will notice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Surface Book or the pen, but it seems you should be able to

- **set button shortcuts on your pen** [image: buttons]
- **then you could launch the Windows Ink Workspace app** [image: workspace]
- **and select *Sketchpad* to get clean canvas to write on**

I can trigger this on my computer with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and it looks to me that there is good chance it won't interfere with your presentation.

Comment: Tried that.  But every time you select sketchpad, you get the same sketchpad, not an additional page, so you have to save keep saving it before you clear it.  And of course, they're not PPT slides.